# How increase background-size: cover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i try to increse and decrese a pic with jquery on mouseenter on mouseleave.
The problem is if i increse background-size:cover to 'background-size': '150%' (example)
and then came back to cover the animation not work anymore

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.img-featured', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.stop().animate({
            'background-size': '150%',
        });
    }).on('mouseleave', '.img-featured', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.stop().animate({
            'background-size': 'cover',
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.test{
width:200px;
}

.img-featured {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:  100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<body>
<div class="test">
<div class="img-featured" style="background-image:url('http://www.bergamonews.it/photogallery_new/images/2016/02/petaloso-533039.660x368.jpg');"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

How can came back to covered picture?

**EDIT Partial Solved**

instead of .animate, use .css and working now

```
 $('body').on('mouseenter', '.img-featured', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({
        'background-size': '150%',
    });
}).on('mouseleave', '.img-featured', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().css({
        'background-size': 'cover',
    });
});
```

Comment: don't you just want to change `100%` in your jquery to `cover`?

Comment: if i put 100% the image is like horizontal ...not is covered...and i not like so

Comment: I have try to put again 'background-size': 'cover' in mouseleave but not working

Comment: Ah, I think it only works with percentages, and won't transition or animate the `cover` value. Though you can transition `scale()` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwjMKm

Comment: thx!! Workign very good

Comment: oh awesome. want me to submit it as an answer? wasn't sure if that would work for you.

Comment: would there be any reason why CSS(transition)  is not to be used ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmZdzK

Comment: @micheal yes sure